# How to get exit status from a Java program in a batch file

Tags: java, linux, batch-file

I'm newbie in batch programming (I don't know much about batch files). My boss has asked me to write a batch file that runs a Java application. The batch file has something like this:

```
echo ロックテーブル削除

java -cp n:\kanesin.root\bin\Sys.Boundary.BatchMain.jar /JobID:BCM0020  
if not ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo Teiji_H01.bat BCM0020 > rerun.bat
    goto ERROREXIT
)
```

but I don't know how the Java application sends the ERRORLEVEL to this batch file. Do I have to return an integer value, or use `System.exit(number);` ?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I have to return an integer value, or use `System.exit(number);` ?

Yes. You set that by using [`System.exit(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-) which (per the Javadoc)

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.